# Use XSLT to "Fill Down" data

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

Is it possible to use XSLT to fill down data. I have searched and can't find anything that helps.

To illustrate, I am getting some XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Record>
       <CompanyName>A</CompanyName>
       <ContactSurname>A</ContactSurname>
       <ContactFirstname>E</ContactFirstname>
       <Address>Address 1</Address>
     </Record>
     <Record>
       <Address>Address 2</Address>
     </Record>
     <Record>
        <Address>Address 3</Address>
     </Record>

    <Record>
       <CompanyName>B</CompanyName>
       <ContactSurname>B</ContactSurname>
       <ContactFirstname>A</ContactFirstname>
       <Address>Address 4</Address>
     </Record>
     <Record>
       <Address>Address 5</Address>
     </Record>
     ....
```

What I need to do is modify each record that does not contain all the elements to add them so the output would be.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Root>
    <Record>
       <CompanyName>A</CompanyName>
       <ContactSurname>A</ContactSurname>
       <ContactFirstname>E</ContactFirstname>
       <Address>Address 1</Address>
     </Record>
     <Record>
       <CompanyName>A</CompanyName>
       <ContactSurname>A</ContactSurname>
       <ContactFirstname>E</ContactFirstname>
       <Address>Address 2</Address>
     </Record>
     <Record>
       <CompanyName>A</CompanyName>
       <ContactSurname>A</ContactSurname>
       <ContactFirstname>E</ContactFirstname>
       <Address>Address 3</Address>
     </Record>

    <Record>
       <CompanyName>B</CompanyName>
       <ContactSurname>B</ContactSurname>
       <ContactFirstname>A</ContactFirstname>
       <Address>Address 4</Address>
     </Record>
     <Record>
       <CompanyName>B</CompanyName>
       <ContactSurname>B</ContactSurname>
       <ContactFirstname>A</ContactFirstname>
       <Address>Address 5</Address>
     </Record>
     ....
```

I can easily use .NET to iterate through the records and create a new XML file, however I thought it may be quicker and simpler to do it this way if it were possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Record">
            <xsl:variable name="stack" select=". | preceding-sibling::Record" />
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="($stack/CompanyName)[last()]"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="($stack/ContactSurname)[last()]"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="($stack/ContactFirstname)[last()]"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="($stack/Address)[last()]"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Considering the comment by Michael Kay below, you might find this faster:

```
<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Record">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="((. | preceding-sibling::Record[CompanyName][1])/CompanyName)[last()]" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="((. | preceding-sibling::Record[ContactSurname][1])/ContactSurname)[last()]" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="((. | preceding-sibling::Record[ContactFirstname][1])/ContactFirstname)[last()]" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="((. | preceding-sibling::Record[Address][1])/Address)[last()]" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That's likely to have O(n^2) performance; if it's too slow, an alternative might be to replace the xsl:copy-of instructions with (e.g.) `<xsl:copy-of select="preceding-sibling::Record[CompanyName][1]/CompanyName"/>`

Comment: @MichaelKay That will not produce the same result.